# How to unit test an async call to a service end point

Tags: java, web-services, asynchronous

The application I work with makes an async call to a third party web service end point and never receives a response. The async call passes a few parameters to the end point.

The method that actually makes the async call preps the objects being passed as parameters and returns an error code if the objects are not valid. But the async call within the method itself does not return. Cannot post code here, but here is the pseudo code:

```
public String makeAsyncCall(Object obj1, Object obj2, Object obj3)
{
    if(isValid(obj1)) //call to external util method to checks if fields are notnull or notempty
    {
        getValueFromObj1(obj1) //call to private method to get a value and process the value
    }
    else
    {
        return errorcode;
    }           
    ..... //other objects are validated

    makeAsyncCall(Object obj1, Object obj2, Object obj3); //returns void
}
```

How would I go about unit testing such a method?

Comment: What about using mocks?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple async-sync adaptor using [FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html)'s [get() method with timeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29).

```
FutureTask<X> callback; // task should be run from the thread receiving async replies
...
invokeWebSericeMethodAsyncAndCallTheArgWhenDone(callback);
X value = callback.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```